# What packages are in different ros dockerhub images?

Tags: ros, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the differences between the different images listed in https://hub.docker.com/_/ros?

For example:

```
noetic-ros-core, noetic-ros-core-focal
noetic-ros-base, noetic-ros-base-focal, noetic
noetic-robot, noetic-robot-focal
noetic-perception, noetic-perception-focal
noetic-ros-core-buster
noetic-ros-base-buster
noetic-robot-buster
noetic-perception-buster
```

The ones listed on the same lines are the same, aliases for each other.  Ubuntu 20.04 is focal, I think buster is just for arm architectures, or maybe even just raspberry pi.  Does `perception` have everything in `robot` but then some more packages on top of that?

Following one of the links leads to
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/df19ab7d5993d3b78a908362cdcd1479a8e78b35/ros/noetic/ubuntu/focal/perception/Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  ros-noetic-perception=1.5.0-1*
```

So the right apt/dpkg command could list everything in ros-noetic-perception or ros-noetic-robot (I'm looking now but I'm not coming up with the right search terms).

I could pull down the images and run `dpkg -l | grep ros-noetic` in them (though I wasn't intending to work with the containers directly, just wanted one for use in a github action).

http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1 has some clues for some of the packages but doesn't quite get there- maybe desktop-full overlaps with ros-perception, but neither is a superset of the other, or it has everything in perception then more besides?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394472/what-packages-are-in-different-ros-dockerhub-images?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2022-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the naming of these images -- and their contents -- follows the *variants* defined in [REP-150: ROS Melodic and Newer Metapackages](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html) (for ROS 2, it's [REP-2001: ROS 2 Variants](https://ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html)).

For `ros_core` for instance:

> The ros_core metapackage composes the core communication protocols. It may not contain any GUI dependencies.
>
> ```
> - ros_core:
>      packages: [catkin, class_loader, cmake_modules, common_msgs, gencpp,
> ```

```
                geneus, genlisp, genmsg, gennodejs, genpy, message_generation,
                message_runtime, pluginlib, ros, ros_comm,
                rosbag_migration_rule, rosconsole, rosconsole_bridge,
                roscpp_core, rosgraph_msgs, roslisp, rospack, std_msgs,
                std_srvs]
```

that's why you only see `apt-get install [..] ros-noetic-perception` in the `Dockerfile`.

It just installs the `perception` variant.

The `focal` and `buster` suffixes are indeed to differentiate between the different OS supported by a particular ROS version.

ROS Noetic supports both Ubuntu Focal and Debian Buster. But the `ros_core` variant is part of both of those.

So to differentiate between them, the OS code name was added, which makes it

> The `ros_core` variant of ROS Noetic on Ubuntu Focal

and similar for Debian Buster.

Those `Dockerfiles` are not written by hand, but generated using the scripts in the [osrf/docker_images](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images) repository. Those scripts parse a large `.yaml` file which contains information on all the different OS + ROS version + variant combinations. See [osrf/docker_images/ros/manifest.yaml](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/85f686512bdfb0ddf2dd187d9aea95c9cebdfc0c/ros/manifest.yaml#L331-L379) for the information used to generate the ROS Noetic images.

The tags for each image are also generated based on this information:

> ```
> noetic:
> ```

```
  eol: 2025-05
  os_names:
    ubuntu:
      os_code_names:
        focal:
          <<: *DEFAULT_ROS1
          archs:
            - amd64
            - arm32v7
            - arm64v8
          tag_names:
            ros-core:
              aliases:
                - "$release_name-ros-core"
                - "$release_name-ros-core-$os_code_name"
    debian:
      [..]
```

See the `aliases` key, which is responsible for the `noetic-ros-core`, `noetic-ros-core-focal` images you found (and which indeed contain the same packages).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-01-17**:
https://ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html answers the `robot` vs. `perception` question- they both use `ros_base` but have nothing in common besides that.

What I really want is a `desktop_full` image, which exists on https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/master/ros/noetic/ubuntu/focal/desktop-full/Dockerfile - but isn't list on dockerhub.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-01-17**:
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/e95025e4b17349438a4b68951bd6d8702b0020be/ros/noetic/debian/buster/Makefile#L18 - there's a `desktop-full` entry but it's commented out, but I can docker pull it and it's listed under osrf https://hub.docker.com/layers/osrf/ros/noetic-desktop-full/images/sha256-32662064d4572123b8e6644bfb1b1b655053e760d10062b7a11e032b75e71929?context=explore  ... but it's 6 months old, so probably an apt update/upgrade is more expensive than a more recent image of noetic-perception or noetic-robot and installing the minimum of additional packages